# Ubuntu 13.04 - Raring Ringtail support

Tags: ubuntu-13.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear Gazebo developers,

Really nice to see a PPA, will Ubuntu 13.10 be supported soon too?

http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/dists/

Personally I had no problems whatsoever in upgrading everything I maintain for 13.10, there are almost no changes compared to 12.10. So, I assume it's just a few minutes of the time of your package maintainer.

Kind regards,

Anne

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3004/ubuntu-13.04---raring-ringtail-support/) by [MrQuincle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/367/mrquincle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-28**:
You say 13.04 in the title but 13.10 in the post. I assume you mean 13.04 in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 1.10 (coming out on Oct. 4th, 2013) will have support for raring.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0